# SQL/SSRS select first weekday on or prior to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello I've converted a spreadsheet into a SSRS report which is run on the 20th of month and I need to pass the 20th of the current month as a default value (start date) either through a custom expression or dataset. If the 20th falls on a Saturday, default to friday 19th. If the 20th falls on Sunday default to Friday 18th. How do I do this and what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: "first weekday prior to the 20th of the current month", as a phrase, would exclude the 20th, so is the right answer for a Monday the 17th, and any other weekday, the 19th?

Comment: sorry i was a bit confused myself about requirement, i've clarified it...

Comment: You can't configure SQL Server Agent to run this job on a variable schedule. You can change date filters inside SQL. If you want a automated varying schedule then use c# or java or whatever: not SQL Server

Comment: Interesting that have downvoted (you got the Critic badge!) answers that have tried to provide SQL solutions for *what you asked*...

Comment: sorry I've done a crap job of explaining what I want... The date function I need is being passed as a default value for a start date in an SSRS report, either as a custom expression or SQL query within a dataset... (I tried to delete this question and recreate making it much clearer but it wouldn't let me...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @daytwenty date;
SET @daytwenty = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, getdate()) ,19) --Get Twentieth Day of current month

SELECT 
      CASE DATEPART(DW,@daytwenty)
         WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(dd, -2, @daytwenty) --When the twentieth day is a Sunday, take two days off
         WHEN 7 THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @daytwenty) --When the twentieth day is a Saturday, take one day off
         ELSE @daytwenty --Else the twentieth day is a weekday already
      END
```

Comment: +1 This will work but you need to make sure that first day of week is Sunday. `set datefirst 7`

Answer (score 0):

You should use Datetime for 2008 version. By writing

```
DECLARE @LatestDate date;
```

in previous version of Sql Server gives compilation error.

```
Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type date.
```

So below is the code **Sql server 2008**

```
DECLARE @LatestDate datetime;
SET @LatestDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, getdate()) ,19) --Get Twentieth Day of current month

SELECT 
      CASE DATEPART(DW,@LatestDate)
         WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(dd, -2, @LatestDate) --When the twentieth day is a Sunday, take two days off
         WHEN 7 THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @LatestDate) --When the twentieth day is a Saturday, take one day off
         ELSE @LatestDate --Else the twentieth day is a weekday already
      END
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what u want,

```
 select case datename(dw, getdate())
 when 'Monday' then 'Friday'
 when 'Tuesday' then 'Monday'
 when 'Wednesday' then 'Tuesday'
 when 'Thursday' then 'Wednesday'
 when 'Friday' then 'Thursday'
 when 'Saturday' then 'Friday'
 when 'Sunday' then 'Friday'
 end
```